# No funciona addEventListener de JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Mi código es el siguiente, y quiero que cuando haga click en el boton con clase active y id btn haga una acción, por ahora un alert para probar, pero igualmente haga click y no muestra el alert:

```
  <div class="container__items-flex">
    <ul>
      <li class="move-0"><a href="#" class="active" id="btn">Menú</a></li>
      <li class="move-1"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li class="move-2"><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
      <li class="move-3"><a href="#">Política</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Ignoren las clases move...

Luego mi código de js es el siguiente:

```
const menu_btn = document.querySelector('btn');

console.log(menu_btn);

if (menu_btn) {
  menu_btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert("Funciona re piola chabón");
  });
}
```

Comment: ¿No será `document.querySelector('#btn');` (?...

Answer (score 4):

Es `document.querySelector('#btn')` el "#" representa un id, o sea es equivalente a `<element id="btn"></element>`, mientras que `document.querySelector('btn')` sería equivalente a `<btn></btn>`, o también podrías usar `document.getElementByID('btn')` para evitar confusiones

Answer (score 1):

El error se encuentra en la siguiente linea de codigo

```
const menu_btn = document.querySelector('btn');
```

si usas `querySelector()`, dentro de las comillas tienes que especificar lo que quieres selecccionar como lo es una clase `.`, id `#`, has de cuenta que estas seleccionando desde css y siguiendo esa misma lógica no te vas a volver a equivocar.

Ahora para corregir el error simplemente modifica el coidgo de la siguiente manera:

```
const menu_btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
```